# How to make Sequelize search by several fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I spent a lot of time to find an answer, but did not find it

So, my problem is - I am trying to make where condition like this:

```
where: {
        [Op.and]:
          [
            { skill: 'IDE', months: { [Op.gte]: 28 } },
            { skill: 'REST', months: { [Op.gte]: 20 } },
          ]
      }
```

But it just does not work
May be it is not right way to do what i need?

Comment: is there an error? what does the query look like?
context would help... maybe you want an Op.or?

Comment: i just got no result

Answer (score 0):

probably you want an `or` like that.

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      { authorId: 12 },
      { authorId: 13 }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually, I need "and", because, user will choose skill and months and add one more skill and month
so, all of that in necessary

Comment: so there is a row with `skill: 'IDE'` AND `skill: 'REST'` ?

Comment: No, it is different rows, but with the same parent_id

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not use it that. You can try below codes.

```
where: {
        [Op.and]:
          [
            { [Op.and]:[{skill:'IDE'},{months:{[Op.gte]:28}] },
            { [Op.and]:[{skill:'REST'},{months:{[Op.gte]:20}] },
          ]
      }
```

Comment: No, its not working, i just got nothing in result